# Selenium WD test for south west airlines

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Can anyone help with this? As a part of learning I'm trying creating selenium web driver test in https://www.southwest.com/. I'm trying create an automated test for flight booking. But i'm not able to get any Gui elements with any locators.

Comment: Which Locator are you using? I tried developer tab and im able to see the elements?

Comment: Can you please share the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below code and able to make it.

I tried till "Price" module though.

```
public class South {
    WebDriver driver;

    @CacheLookup
    @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='air-city-departure']") 
    WebElement dept;

    @CacheLookup
    @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='air-city-arrival']") 
    WebElement arrive;

    @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='trip-type-one-way']") 
    WebElement onewayRadio;

    @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='jb-booking-form-submit-button']") 
    WebElement search;

    @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='Out1B']") 
    WebElement flightRadio;

    @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='priceItinerarySubmit']") 
    WebElement continueButton;

    @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='business_select_upgrade_modal']/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/input") 
    WebElement continueButton2;

    @Test 
    public void f() throws InterruptedException {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
        driver.get("https://www.southwest.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        onewayRadio.click();
        dept.sendKeys("MSY");
        arrive.sendKeys("ALB");
        search.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        flightRadio.click();
        continueButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        continueButton2.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you much,It's working fine. but I use the basic automation script to get the elements, I didn't use page factories. eg:                       @AfterTest
 public void bookFlight()
 {
  WebDriver dr;
  dr.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='trip-type-one-way']")).click();
  dr.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='air-city-departure']")).sendKeys("SFO");
  dr.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='air-city-arrival']")).click();
  dr.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='booking-form--flight-panel']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a")).click();
  dr.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='calendar-august-23']")).click();

Comment: @Julie Modified "By.id" to "By.xpath" and it worked. Observe the code,  
 dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='trip-type-one-way']")).click();
 dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='air-city-arrival']")).sendKeys("ALB"); 
  dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='air-city-departure']")).sendKeys("MSY");
  dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='jb-booking-form-submit-button']")).click();
  dr.findElement(By.xpath((".//*[@id='Out1B']") )).click();
  dr.findElement(By.xpath((".//*[@id='priceItinerarySubmit']") )).click();